# A Lot of Thought

Tags: visual, number-sequence, sequence

[image]

One of my favourite school time riddles! What is the number of the parking space containing the car?

Comment: Got to love the artist’s effort here, drawing the lines and numbers in neat perspective and then just plonking down a car silhouette seen from straight above, so that the car seems to be standing on its exhaust pipe with its front end a metre or two off the ground. :-)

Comment: @Bass [Lowrider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowrider#/media/File:Fiestas_Patrias_Parade,_South_Park,_Seattle,_2015_-_358_-_lowriders_(21403531350).jpg) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well known one.

The space number is

> 87.

Try

> reading the numbers upside down
>  [image]

Comment: Correct answer should be *L8*  ... that is look straight...right up...(No business of turning it up side down)..

Answer (score 2):

> It's 87. Just take a look upside down. 86,87,88,89,90,91. It's that series